# XML HTTP request fails to send request to my PHP file from JS

Tags: php, jquery, xml, cookies, xmlhttprequest

In `log.js` the following function is not working for some reason and I really want it to work and maybe someone knows how to use post instead of get so that I don't have to use cookie to retrieve login info in PHP file

```
function refreshData(file,msg){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", file);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      swal(msg);
    };
  }
}
```

but without request when I replace that function with this one everything works fine but it opens up a new tab

```
function refreshData(file,msg){
  window.open("login.php");
}
```

Here is my `index.php`:

```html
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script src="/cafe/script/main2.js"></script>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../style/main.css' media='screen' />
</head>
<body>

<div align='left' class='nav-top'>
 <a class='logo' id='logo'>kush.</a>
 <a class='logo2' id='logo'>by</a>
 <a href='../novosti' id='btnNews'>news</a>
 <a href='../zavedenia' id='btnPlaces'>places</a>
 <a href='../kontakty' id='btnContacts'>contacts</a>
 <a href='../blog' id='btnBlog'>blog</a>
<script src='log.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my log.js

```js
var authentication = "no";
var authentication=getCookie("auth");
var email=getCookie("email");

 if(authentication=="logged_in")
 {
  //some code
  if(email.indexOf("@cafe.eda")>-1)
  {
   loadCafeProfile(email);
  }
  else
  {
   loadPersonProfile(email);
  }
 }
 else
 {
  //some code
  var login = document.getElementById("btnLogIn");
  login.addEventListener('click', logIn);
 }

 function logIn()
 {
  var email = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("InputPass").value;
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i;
  if(!validateEmail(email))
  {
   swal("check  email");
  }
  else if(pass.length<6)
  {
   swal("max password length 6 char");
  }
  else
  {
   setCookie("email",email,1);
   setCookie("pass",pass,1);
   refreshData("login.php","login in");
  }
 }

function validateEmail(email)
{
    //email validation
    return //true false
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires="expires="+d.toGMTString();
 document.cookie=cname+"="+cvalue+";"+expires+";path=/";
}

function getCookie( name )
{
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    var end = null;
    if (begin == -1)
    {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0)
        {
         return null;
        }
        end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    } 
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1)
        {
            end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end) ).replace(/"/g, '');
}



function loadCafeProfile(email)
 {
  //load cafe profile
 }
 function loadPersonProfile(email)
 {
  //loads persons profile
 }

function refreshData(file,msg){
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", file);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          swal(msg);
        };
      }
    }
```

here is mine login.php

```html
<?php
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("../../db.ini");
$servername=$ini_array['sn'];
$username=$ini_array['un'];
$password=$ini_array['pw'];
$dbname=$ini_array['dn'];
 setcookie("jumbo","jumbo",time()+3600,'/');
 $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
 
 //check conection
 if(!$conn)
 {
  setcookie('error','connection_fail',time()+3600,'/');
  //header("Location:../cafe");
 }
 $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_COOKIE['email']);
 $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_COOKIE['pass']);

 $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

// Validate e-mail and password
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $pass))
{
 $pass=md5(sha1(md5($pass)));
 if(strpos($email,'@cafe.eda')!==false)
 {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE email='".$email."' and parol='".$pass."'";
 }
 else
 {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM rebyata WHERE email='".$email."' and parol='".$pass."'";
 }
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
 {
  setcookie('auth','logged_in',time()+3600*2400,'/');
  setcookie('ses',md5($email.$pass),time()+3600*2400,'/');
  //echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
 }
 else
 {
  setcookie('error','loginfail',time()+3600*2400,'/');
  //header("Location:../cafe");
 }
}
else
{
 setcookie('error','wrong_input',time()+3600*2400,'/');
 //header("Location:../cafe");
}
?>
```

Comment: You best look into using `Prepared Statements`

Comment: Why are you storing the login info inside of the cookie? Wouldn't it be best to pass it with the `xmlhttprequest`?

Comment: I dont know how to pass it with xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so instead of using `cookies` to transfer data with your `xmlHttpRequest()` you can pass information using the `send()` function.

Web APIs | MDN:

> send() accepts an optional parameter which lets you specify the request's body; this is primarily used for request such as PUT. If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and request body is set to null.

---

### Objects

`send()` allows for parameters; in this case you can pass the username and password inside of an `object`:

```
.send({
  user: email,
  pass: password
});
```

Then in PHP just get the `$_POST` data into the correct array:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $email = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
}
```

---

### Serialize

Or you can serialize the data into a string:

```
var params = "email="+ email + "&pass="+ password;
```

Then send it:

```
.send(params);
```

If you are using jQuery you can also use their handy little `serialize()` function.

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Which will simply put the items into a string as shown above.

Once you receive the data in the `login.php` file you can parse the string if serialized, and if you put them into the object, you can just use your standard `$_POST` variable.

```
if($_POST)
{
    parse_str($_POST, $form);
    // you can now get the post data into an array:
    $form['email'];
    $form['password'];
}
```

---

### Resolution

Your `login()` function:

```
function logIn() {
    var email = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("InputPass").value;
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i;
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        swal("check  email");
    } else if (pass.length < 6) {
        swal("max password length 6 char");
    } else {
        refreshData("login.php", {
                email: email,
                password: pass
        });
    }
}
```

Then your `refreshData()` function would look like this:

```
function refreshData(file, data) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", file);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            swal(msg);
        };
    }
}
```

---

### Promises

Or, better yet, you can use `fetch()` which is a better (newer) alternative to `xmlHttpRequest`. You can also use promises - which work very well.

```
function refreshData(url, data) {
    return fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: 'no-cache',
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
            console.log("Error: ", e);
    });
}
```

That is the new method of implementing AJAX call, if you are interested look [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), they are very good and there are also good examples.

Comment: I used function refreshData(file, data) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", file);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            swal(msg);
        };
    }
}

it works I am getting logged in but after a few tries of clicking not from the first button click

Comment: @mishasachenko sweet... That's good to know... That's usually how JS works

Comment: how can I make it log in from one click of a button though, cause I am pressing the log in button more then one time in order to run that function and hope to get logged in

Comment: I am not sure man... It shouldn't be this way; it would be how you handle your form events. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Everything works perfect now)) I was submitting form on a click of a button what refreshed my page and didnt let the callback function to run) I just removed <form></form> and it works perfectly fine from one click like it is suppose to do)))) took me hours to figure it out)